# How can I avoid a RabbitMQ producer disconnection?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to set up a simple message producer along with its consumer using RabbitMQ in python with the pika library.

Whenever my producer stays idle for too long, the connection closes and I get an error if I try to send another message on the same connection. I read it is not good practice to open and close channels each time I want to send a message, but I don't know exactly at which rate I am going to send messages.

In this example, I send a message, then wait for 5 minutes and try to send another message, which gives my an error message.

The code:

```py
import os
import pika

# Connection details
RABBITMQ_HOST = os.getenv("RABBITMQ_HOST", "localhost")
RABBITMQ_PORT = os.getenv("RABBITMQ_PORT", "5672")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue_name = "TEST_QUEUE"
    parameters = parameters=pika.ConnectionParameters(host=RABBITMQ_HOST, port=RABBITMQ_PORT)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue_name, durable=True, auto_delete=False)

    channel.basic_publish(exchange="", routing_key=queue_name, body="message 1")
    time.sleep(300)
    channel.basic_publish(exchange="", routing_key=queue_name, body="message 2")
```

The error message when trying to send the second message:

```
channel.basic_publish(exchange="", routing_key=queue_name, body="message 2")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 2265, in basic_publish
    self._flush_output()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1353, in _flush_output
    self._connection._flush_output(lambda: self.is_closed, *waiters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 523, in _flush_output
    raise self._closed_result.value.error
pika.exceptions.StreamLostError: Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')
```

I have read some documentation about heartbeats and I tried to play with that, but it didn't work and I don't fully understand how it would modify my code's behavior.

What should I do in my case to avoid this error ?